# Unique Auto-incrementing ID's, based on unique users

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

Currently, when a customer adds a new patch, `patch_id` will be increased by one. However, this affects other customers as well. Say customer `A` adds a new patch, then the next patch customer `B` adds, will be an even higher ID.

I want to separate these, as i use the `ID` in the url, on a customer-basis. And i don't find it appropriate that a user will see `patch/324` in his URL, if he's got only 3 patches. Each patch has a `customer_id`, equal to the corresponding customer.

How can i achieve this? I've been searching the internet far and wide, but i really don't know the proper way to express this question in short, to find a relative search-term.

Comment: You'll probably need a customer-patch table with the auto increment on it. Or provide the patch number to the DB engine procedurally. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26578313/how-do-i-create-a-sequence-in-mysql

Comment: I think you are trying to solve a non-problem.  What difference does it make what variables show up in the address bar?

Comment: @DanBracuk I just don't want new customers to log into a personalized user interface, with a quite high patch ID in their URL. I want it to feel more unique

Comment: Why don't you make a slug

Comment: @NWest Cheers for the response. Useful link! I couldn't find anything usable myself, as i didn't know how to express this question.

Comment: Add a `patch_id` field to your `customers` table and increment it manually or something like that.

Comment: Check out Hashids package this does a nice job to hide your system ids. You can use different recipes for the hash per model so your hashs are also internally unique