# auto increment every 10 rows

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

I'm using PHP. I will create a a column in my database that will have a value, such as `1`. I want to set this value to auto-increment each time it passes 10 rows:

In other words:

```
1st row will have the value = 1
2nd row will have the value = 1
........
........

10th row will have the value = 1 

11th row the value will auto increment and change to be = to 2
```

Comment: Don't bother storing this kind of data. Just calculate it 'on-the-fly'

Comment: @Andrew 38 - If you mention your use with that column value, I think I can give you a better solution

Comment: Create two fields, the first is the classic auto increment and the second should be populated with a stored procedure.

Comment: I want the value of this coulmn to display it

Comment: As @Strawberry said, this is probably better implemented as a calculated field in a query.  How will you be consuming the data?

Comment: Getting a good grib of the consumption is hard, it will depend.

Comment: `output_id = ceil(row_id/10)`

Comment: what defines the ORDER of these rows? (could you possibly insert a row between 5 and 6 after the 11th row has been generated?  causing 10 to become 11 and thus needing to change to 2?)

Comment: Perform (rownum/10) +1 and decide the value to be stored. For eg, 6th row, 6/10 +1 = 1, 100th row,= 11 and so on. No access to editor. Else would have answered

Comment: The rows are ordered with a classic id auto increment field

Comment: @I_am_Batman that would be false for rows = 10 , 20, 30, it would give id 2,3,4 etc.

Comment: @martin.. I stand corrected. But that can be tweaked around a bit.

Comment: My code a few comments up does what you're stating :-) @I_am_Batman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution for  you

Assume you have a table named `table1` and that table have following structure

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Note that `id` column is auto increment

Following query will give you the result you want

```
select a.id,FLOOR((a.id-1)/10)+1 as calculated_value from table1 a
```

In the result `calculated_value` will give you the result.

**If you are interested, some additional information**

Assume you fear that taking auto increment column for calculation is risky then you can use following

```
    SELECT t.id,t.name ,(@num:=@num+1) AS i,FLOOR((@num-1)/10)+1 
as calculated_value  FROM table1 t CROSS JOIN (SELECT @num:=0) AS 
dummy ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: Note that this solution assumes no gaps/deletions

Comment: you could bundle your example in a sequence and it will work. see this example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26578313/how-do-i-create-a-sequence-in-mysql

Comment: @Andrew38 - can you explain that with an example?

Comment: @Andrew38 - Kindly provide your table's structure too. Also mention using which column you are ordering your output

Comment: @Andrew38 - You mentioned some boolean values too right? I cant see that in your last comment. Can you add your table structure in your question?

Comment: @Andrew38- In this case your select statement should use order by some column right? Which column you are using for that?

Comment: @Andrew38 -  You need to select data from your table for processing. In this case it is better to specify and order by condition in your select query. For example select * from table1 order by id. Do you have any requirement like that ?

Comment: @Andrew38 - you will read row with seen=0 then after processing you will make seen=1. is that happening in your case?

Comment: i'm calculating auto increment value and then calculating your required number

Comment: @Andrew38- is that problem solved?

Comment: What does the t.id, t.name and @cnt refer to ?

Comment: @Andrew38 - that query using my sample table mentioned in first part of the answer