# How to Fill a table with data without a stored procedure/function?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

The goal is to create and populate a table with MySQL on the server. The table will be populated with 500 randomly selected names, addresses, and emails.

I created a procedure to complete this task, but it seems that my account does not have the permissions necessary to create stored procedures/functions, which is what every example I can find uses.

When I execute the file I get the following error:

ERROR 10444 (42000): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' to database 'db_name'

The file does create the table, it just doesn't get populated. 
How can I modify my code so that I don't need a stored procedure?

```
use dbName;

drop table contacts;

create table dbName.contacts(
uid int(4) unsigned auto_increment primary key,
fname varchar(255),
lname varchar(255),
address varchar(255),
st varchar(2),
zipc int(5),
pNum int(10),
email varchar(255)
);

DELIMITER ##
create procedure fill_contacts_table()
begin

DECLARE counter INT;
SET counter = 0;

    while counter < 500 do

            insert into contacts(
                fname,
                lname,
                address,
                st,
                zipc,
                pNum,
                email) 
            VALUES(
            ELT(1 + FLOOR(RAND()*100),
                'Willodean', 
                'Florentino',
                'Gale',  
                'Tasia', 
                'Bruno',  
                'Shanice',  
                'Chun',  
                'Moses',  
                'Fritz',  
                'Lincoln',  
                'Jeremy',  
                'Millie',  
                'Lorita',  
                'Quinn',  
                'Tennie',  
                'Gretchen',  
                'Mallory',  
                'Adolph',  
                'Jolene',  
                'Margarete',  
                'Charmaine',  
                'Pandora',  
                'Stephnie',  
                'Zelma',  
                'Vena',  
                'Joan',  
                'Berniece',  
                'Leonida',  
                'Sunni',  
                'Tonda',  
                'Keena',  
                'Evalyn',  
                'Kaylene',  
                'Rubie',  
                'Elia',  
                'Lorrine',  
                'Stasia',  
                'Loura',  
                'Rosie',  
                'Fredricka',  
                'Shawn',  
                'Felipa',  
                'Carmel',  
                'Kay',  
                'Ashanti',  
                'Helga',  
                'Charlotte',  
                'Hisako',  
                'Cheyenne ', 
                'Rudy',
                'Pearline', 
                'Isabelle',  
                'Hillary',  
                'Janett',  
                'Freddy',  
                'Kristyn',  
                'Karine',  
                'Delana',  
                'George',  
                'Marianela',  
                'Laurine',  
                'Clarissa',  
                'Han',  
                'Genny', 
                'Melita',  
                'Donette',  
                'Callie',  
                'Lavelle',  
                'Sharonda',  
                'Kirsten',  
                'Joanna',  
                'Muriel',  
                'Sherwood',  
                'Rebbeca',  
                'Jonah',  
                'Ellie',  
                'Marita',  
                'Fumiko',  
                'Gretchen',  
                'Stanford',  
                'Cecilia',  
                'Audry',  
                'Jermaine', 
                'Stephane',  
                'Cathleen',  
                'Neida',  
                'Reynaldo',  
                'Evelin',  
                'Irving',  
                'Sherril',  
                'Prudence',  
                'Karri',  
                'Berta',  
                'Valeri',  
                'Alyson',  
                'Tommy',  
                'Reina',  
                'Caren', 
                'Yon',  
                'Tereasa'),
            ELT(1 + FLOOR(RAND()*100),
                'Ress',
                'Dusek',
                'Eilers',
                'Brasch',
                'Ascencio',
                'Marti',
                'Glaze',
                'Pardon',
                'Alleman',
                'Cichon',
                'Weaver',
                'Clifford',
                'Herring',
                'Shoe',
                'Rey',
                'Mccay',
                'Mohl',
                'Mayo',
                'Romberger',
                'Dutta',
                'Tindal',
                'Clarkson',
                'Hellyer',
                'Albaugh',
                'Barfield',
                'Bazan',
                'Doubleday',
                'Freudenthal',
                'Motton',
                'Bertram',
                'Wisneski',
                'Luongo',
                'Maddocks',
                'Mcwilliam',
                'Debord',
                'Goldner',
                'Barham',
                'Cogley',
                'Maria',
                'Harms',
                'Parmer', 
                'Irion',
                'Carmean',
                'Nilson',
                'Corrao',
                'Giesler',
                'Winkel',
                'Jepson',
                'Kean',
                'Viens',
                'Rhett',
                'Feather',
                'Sonnier',
                'Newland', 
                'Lachermeier', 
                'Counter', 
                'Scharf', 
                'Barrentine', 
                'Reising', 
                'Kenny',
                'Jett', 
                'Deshong', 
                'Amico', 
                'Kieser', 
                'Kinsey',
                'Yun', 
                'Rohloff', 
                'Farinas', 
                'Abshire', 
                'Jefferson',
                'Forbis', 
                'Fortune', 
                'Osbourn', 
                'Siguenza', 
                'Davilla', 
                'Mcelhannon', 
                'Taniguchi', 
                'Spiegel', 
                'Karst', 
                'Polito', 
                'Montijo', 
                'Ager', 
                'Gee', 
                'Clutter', 
                'Stgeorge', 
                'Masterson', 
                'Inglis', 
                'Riemann',
                'Auxier', 
                'Charest', 
                'Westbrook', 
                'Bensen', 
                'Kotek', 
                'Mullens', 
                'Chatterton', 
                'Oommen', 
                'Delia', 
                'Jack', 
                'Zahm', 
                'Pfau'),
            ELT(1 + FLOOR(RAND()*100),
                '104 Green Court',
                '195 Central St.',
                '93 Race Road',
                '643 Penn St.',
                '75 Country Club Ave.',
                '328 North Warren Drive',
                '29 Bridgeton Street',
                '981 Virginia St.',
                '47 Snake Hill Ave.',
                '9784 Broad St.',
                '279 Livingston Drive',
                '555 Orange Street',
                '37 Summer Dr.',
                '95 Prairie St.', 
                '37 Fairground St.', 
                '965 Heather Avenue', 
                '290 Division St.', 
                '372 Plumb Branch St.', 
                '690 Ramblewood St.', 
                '40 Fremont Court', 
                '337C Alton Court', 
                '315 Alderwood St.', 
                '47 Mill Pond Drive', 
                '9815 Santa Clara Court', 
                '9 Fulton Ave.', 
                '960 Bradford Rd.', 
                '61 Peg Shop Dr.', 
                '810 South Dr.', 
                '6 NE. Cardinal Dr.', 
                '7438 Bishop Street', 
                '631 North Gulf Ave.', 
                '94 Clark St.', 
                '60 Williams Dr.', 
                '342 High Ridge Drive', 
                '9703 Gonzales Lane', 
                '9127 Alton Road', 
                '97 Maiden Drive', 
                '387 Lafayette Avenue', 
                '8688 Glen Eagles Avenue', 
                '7057 Sherman Street', 
                '7813 Pierce St.', 
                '83 Woodsman Lane', 
                '7238 West Laurel Ave.', 
                '553 Tunnel Court', 
                '8825 Del Monte St.', 
                '984 East Orchard Drive', 
                '88 Princess St.', 
                '40 E. Wakehurst Lane', 
                '8893 Glenlake Dr.', 
                '4 School Rd.', 
                '7239 SE. Thompson Lane', 
                '627 Warren Ave.',
                '595 Purple Finch Street', 
                '8194 Valley View St.', 
                '259B Randall Mill Ave.', 
                '9460 Spring St.', 
                '9810 Henry Street', 
                '203 E. Eagle Circle', 
                '9582 South Charles Lane', 
                '40 Brewery Ave.', 
                '19 Fulton St.', 
                '340 Edgewater St.', 
                '330 Golden Star Drive', 
                '616 Lexington Ave.', 
                '2 S. Peg Shop St.', 
                '8845 Sutor Rd.', 
                '9919 Southampton Ave.', 
                '50 E. University Ave.', 
                '200 Ryan Ave.', 
                '38 Walnutwood Road', 
                '81 East Victoria Dr.', 
                '6 S. Rocky River Rd.', 
                '549 Princeton Court', 
                '9777 Sherman St.', 
                '7073 Main Street', 
                '406 Queen Dr.', 
                '874 Squaw Creek St.', 
                '9 W. Rose St.', 
                '27 6th Ave.', 
                '135 Cobblestone St.', 
                '531 La Sierra Avenue', 
                '253 East Fawn Ave.', 
                '17 SW. Hillside St.', 
                '5 Tower St.', 
                '69 Smith Court', 
                '395 Foster St.', 
                '20 Race Lane', 
                '9073 Wagon Dr.',
                '20 Fawn Dr.', 
                '195 Central St.', 
                '14 S. Cambridge St.', 
                '535 Griffin Street', 
                '643 Penn Street', 
                '19 Cemetery Dr.', 
                '75 Country Club Ave.', 
                '439 Military Rd.', 
                '285 Philmont Court', 
                '405 Valley View St.', 
                '8662 Magnolia Dr.', 
                '7781 Country Club St.'),
            ELT(1 + FLOOR(RAND()*51),
                'AL',
                'AK',
                'AZ',
                'AR',
                'CA',
                'CO',
                'CT',
                'DE',
                'FL',
                'GA',
                'HI',
                'ID',
                'IL',
                'IN',
                'IA',
                'KS',
                'KY',
                'LA',
                'ME',
                'MD',
                'MA',
                'MI',
                'MN',
                'MS',
                'MO',
                'MT',
                'NE',
                'NV',
                'NH',
                'NJ',
                'NM',
                'NY',
                'NC',
                'ND',
                'OH',
                'OK',
                'OR',
                'PA',
                'RI',
                'SC',
                'SD',
                'TN',
                'TX',
                'UT',
                'VT',
                'VA',
                'WA',
                'WV',
                'WI',
                'WY',
                'DC'),
            ELT(1 + FLOOR(RAND()*100),
                '11720',
                '44133',
                '39564',
                '07103',
                '41018',
                '45211',
                '34711',
                '33904',
                '08021',
                '45040',
                '12401',
                '20715',
                '45103',
                '19038',
                '32303',
                '32958',
                '19468',
                '85302',
                '37076',
                '48021',
                '43512',
                '08060',
                '15206',
                '07840',
                '33139',
                '30040',
                '27529',
                '48101',
                '85224',
                '71730',
                '53066',
                '19454',
                '02072',
                '02127',
                '32904',
                '44145',
                '83651',
                '30126',
                '11572',
                '60101',
                '20874',
                '20707',
                '68107',
                '30294',
                '11552',
                '48310',
                '07080',
                '32955',
                '01845',
                '02155',
                '04106',
                '08540',
                '06484',
                '60435',
                '45066',
                '32707',
                '16601',
                '21771',
                '52501',
                '22304',
                '60451',
                '60466',
                '56401',
                '08857',
                '50310',
                '55316',
                '21009',
                '46304',
                '02131',
                '29646',
                '37849',
                '33702',
                '48178',
                '28655',
                '08520',
                '53051',
                '74820',
                '11417',
                '55343',
                '13501',
                '02148',
                '22041',
                '34787',
                '18015',
                '11701',
                '48067',
                '32003',
                '32250',
                '07666',
                '01801',
                '26508',
                '06492',
                '37072',
                '44266',
                '20832',
                '55330',
                '20705',
                '60133',
                '37388',
                '30188'),
            ELT(1 + FLOOR(RAND()*100),
                '5326650789',
                '5458797497',
                '3969507190',
                '7899779099',
                '5737791024',
                '7152078410',
                '1585609748',
                '9114083701',
                '3319518922',
                '4097559835',
                '7795824751',
                '8152827507',
                '4932036403',
                '6402549987',
                '4342372370',
                '1818285402',
                '7764560114',
                '5052529831',
                '5638654168',
                '5533069282',
                '4588207833',
                '9772641803',
                '2105777477',
                '5487138355',
                '8157763224',
                '6076582385',
                '3091969824',
                '4599611212',
                '1622356799',
                '2193172740',
                '3802198191',
                '8874918768',
                '3527695220',
                '1468081570',
                '8781101437',
                '1783794554',
                '4147642090',
                '6946664816',
                '5259058695',
                '1915347568',
                '7271267139',
                '6915931769',
                '6009627523',
                '9326664619',
                '5669870035',
                '8502271545',
                '9069278491',
                '3309903311',
                '6764406845',
                '9709978941',
                '4967657222',
                '6681379186',
                '6876692503',
                '9115377994',
                '4152903971',
                '3221536656',
                '6531287939',
                '1333154307',
                '1989681996',
                '9823062288',
                '4941263197',
                '8242856770',
                '4085259464',
                '5644693994',
                '2471816666',
                '7743998254',
                '4384095056',
                '8761651796',
                '6535832572',
                '6411644955',
                '9128111230',
                '6084608842',
                '3385174240',
                '2605959727',
                '5443426087',
                '6625356226',
                '4048849246',
                '3775164894',
                '6278296182',
                '3357967793',
                '9195838006',
                '5634927312',
                '7928037269',
                '1512947086',
                '2287557623',
                '1797525964',
                '2979326380',
                '9379217217',
                '8984965224',
                '6219840588',
                '2308367597',
                '6971476470',
                '2085510840',
                '7069816501',
                '2994249472',
                '7672890630',
                '4708647664',
                '9064472436',
                '7391029735',
                '2793660389'),
            ELT(1 + FLOOR(RAND()*500),
                'myemail.1@e.mail',
                'myemail.2@e.mail',
                'myemail.3@e.mail',
                'myemail.4@e.mail',
                'myemail.5@e.mail',
                'myemail.6@e.mail',
                'myemail.7@e.mail',
                'myemail.8@e.mail',
                'myemail.9@e.mail',
                'myemail.10@e.mail',
                'myemail.11@e.mail',
                'myemail.12@e.mail',
                'myemail.13@e.mail',
                'myemail.14@e.mail',
                'myemail.15@e.mail',
                'myemail.16@e.mail',
                'myemail.17@e.mail',
                'myemail.18@e.mail',
                'myemail.19@e.mail',
                'myemail.20@e.mail',
                'myemail.21@e.mail',
                'myemail.22@e.mail',
                'myemail.23@e.mail',
                'myemail.24@e.mail',
                'myemail.25@e.mail',
                'myemail.26@e.mail',
                'myemail.27@e.mail',
                'myemail.28@e.mail',
                'myemail.29@e.mail',
                'myemail.30@e.mail',
                'myemail.31@e.mail',
                'myemail.32@e.mail',
                'myemail.33@e.mail',
                'myemail.34@e.mail',
                'myemail.35@e.mail',
                'myemail.36@e.mail',
                'myemail.37@e.mail',
                'myemail.38@e.mail',
                'myemail.39@e.mail',
                'myemail.40@e.mail',
                'myemail.41@e.mail',
                'myemail.42@e.mail',
                'myemail.43@e.mail',
                'myemail.44@e.mail',
                'myemail.45@e.mail',
                'myemail.46@e.mail',
                'myemail.47@e.mail',
                'myemail.48@e.mail',
                'myemail.49@e.mail',
                'myemail.50@e.mail',
                'myemail.51@e.mail',
                'myemail.52@e.mail',
                'myemail.53@e.mail',
                'myemail.54@e.mail',
                'myemail.55@e.mail',
                'myemail.56@e.mail',
                'myemail.57@e.mail',
                'myemail.58@e.mail',
                'myemail.59@e.mail',
                'myemail.60@e.mail',
                'myemail.61@e.mail',
                'myemail.62@e.mail',
                'myemail.63@e.mail',
                'myemail.64@e.mail',
                'myemail.65@e.mail',
                'myemail.66@e.mail',
                'myemail.67@e.mail',
                'myemail.69@e.mail',
                'myemail.69@e.mail',
                'myemail.70@e.mail',
                'myemail.71@e.mail',
                'myemail.72@e.mail',
                'myemail.73@e.mail',
                'myemail.74@e.mail',
                'myemail.75@e.mail',
                'myemail.76@e.mail',
                'myemail.77@e.mail',
                'myemail.78@e.mail',
                'myemail.79@e.mail',
                'myemail.80@e.mail',
                'myemail.81@e.mail',
                'myemail.82@e.mail',
                'myemail.83@e.mail',
                'myemail.84@e.mail',
                'myemail.85@e.mail',
                'myemail.86@e.mail',
                'myemail.87@e.mail',
                'myemail.88@e.mail',
                'myemail.89@e.mail',
                'myemail.90@e.mail',
                'myemail.91@e.mail',
                'myemail.92@e.mail',
                'myemail.93@e.mail',
                'myemail.94@e.mail',
                'myemail.95@e.mail',
                'myemail.96@e.mail',
                'myemail.97@e.mail',
                'myemail.98@e.mail',
                'myemail.99@e.mail',
                'myemail.100@e.mail',
                'myemail.101@e.mail',
                'myemail.102@e.mail',
                'myemail.103@e.mail',
                'myemail.104@e.mail',
                'myemail.105@e.mail',
                'myemail.106@e.mail',
                'myemail.107@e.mail',
                'myemail.108@e.mail',
                'myemail.109@e.mail',
                'myemail.110@e.mail',
                'myemail.111@e.mail',
                'myemail.112@e.mail',
                'myemail.113@e.mail',
                'myemail.114@e.mail',
                'myemail.115@e.mail',
                'myemail.116@e.mail',
                'myemail.117@e.mail',
                'myemail.118@e.mail',
                'myemail.119@e.mail',
                'myemail.120@e.mail',
                'myemail.121@e.mail',
                'myemail.122@e.mail',
                'myemail.123@e.mail',
                'myemail.124@e.mail',
                'myemail.125@e.mail',
                'myemail.126@e.mail',
                'myemail.127@e.mail',
                'myemail.128@e.mail',
                'myemail.129@e.mail',
                'myemail.130@e.mail',
                'myemail.131@e.mail',
                'myemail.132@e.mail',
                'myemail.133@e.mail',
                'myemail.134@e.mail',
                'myemail.135@e.mail',
                'myemail.136@e.mail',
                'myemail.137@e.mail',
                'myemail.138@e.mail',
                'myemail.139@e.mail',
                'myemail.140@e.mail',
                'myemail.141@e.mail',
                'myemail.142@e.mail',
                'myemail.143@e.mail',
                'myemail.144@e.mail',
                'myemail.145@e.mail',
                'myemail.146@e.mail',
                'myemail.147@e.mail',
                'myemail.148@e.mail',
                'myemail.149@e.mail',
                'myemail.150@e.mail',
                'myemail.151@e.mail',
                'myemail.152@e.mail',
                'myemail.153@e.mail',
                'myemail.154@e.mail',
                'myemail.155@e.mail',
                'myemail.156@e.mail',
                'myemail.157@e.mail',
                'myemail.158@e.mail',
                'myemail.159@e.mail',
                'myemail.160@e.mail',
                'myemail.161@e.mail',
                'myemail.162@e.mail',
                'myemail.163@e.mail',
                'myemail.164@e.mail',
                'myemail.165@e.mail',
                'myemail.166@e.mail',
                'myemail.167@e.mail',
                'myemail.168@e.mail',
                'myemail.169@e.mail',
                'myemail.170@e.mail',
                'myemail.171@e.mail',
                'myemail.172@e.mail',
                'myemail.173@e.mail',
                'myemail.174@e.mail',
                'myemail.175@e.mail',
                'myemail.176@e.mail',
                'myemail.177@e.mail',
                'myemail.178@e.mail',
                'myemail.179@e.mail',
                'myemail.180@e.mail',
                'myemail.181@e.mail',
                'myemail.182@e.mail',
                'myemail.183@e.mail',
                'myemail.184@e.mail',
                'myemail.185@e.mail',
                'myemail.186@e.mail',
                'myemail.187@e.mail',
                'myemail.188@e.mail',
                'myemail.189@e.mail',
                'myemail.190@e.mail',
                'myemail.191@e.mail',
                'myemail.192@e.mail',
                'myemail.193@e.mail',
                'myemail.194@e.mail',
                'myemail.195@e.mail',
                'myemail.196@e.mail',
                'myemail.197@e.mail',
                'myemail.198@e.mail',
                'myemail.199@e.mail',
                'myemail.200@e.mail',
                'myemail.201@e.mail',
                'myemail.202@e.mail',
                'myemail.203@e.mail',
                'myemail.204@e.mail',
                'myemail.205@e.mail',
                'myemail.206@e.mail',
                'myemail.207@e.mail',
                'myemail.208@e.mail',
                'myemail.209@e.mail',
                'myemail.210@e.mail',
                'myemail.211@e.mail',
                'myemail.212@e.mail',
                'myemail.213@e.mail',
                'myemail.214@e.mail',
                'myemail.215@e.mail',
                'myemail.216@e.mail',
                'myemail.217@e.mail',
                'myemail.218@e.mail',
                'myemail.219@e.mail',
                'myemail.220@e.mail',
                'myemail.221@e.mail',
                'myemail.222@e.mail',
                'myemail.223@e.mail',
                'myemail.224@e.mail',
                'myemail.225@e.mail',
                'myemail.226@e.mail',
                'myemail.227@e.mail',
                'myemail.228@e.mail',
                'myemail.229@e.mail',
                'myemail.230@e.mail',
                'myemail.231@e.mail',
                'myemail.232@e.mail',
                'myemail.233@e.mail',
                'myemail.234@e.mail',
                'myemail.235@e.mail',
                'myemail.236@e.mail',
                'myemail.237@e.mail',
                'myemail.238@e.mail',
                'myemail.239@e.mail',
                'myemail.240@e.mail',
                'myemail.241@e.mail',
                'myemail.242@e.mail',
                'myemail.243@e.mail',
                'myemail.244@e.mail',
                'myemail.245@e.mail',
                'myemail.246@e.mail',
                'myemail.247@e.mail',
                'myemail.248@e.mail',
                'myemail.249@e.mail',
                'myemail.250@e.mail',
                'myemail.251@e.mail',
                'myemail.252@e.mail',
                'myemail.253@e.mail',
                'myemail.254@e.mail',
                'myemail.255@e.mail',
                'myemail.256@e.mail',
                'myemail.257@e.mail',
                'myemail.258@e.mail',
                'myemail.259@e.mail',
                'myemail.260@e.mail',
                'myemail.261@e.mail',
                'myemail.262@e.mail',
                'myemail.263@e.mail',
                'myemail.264@e.mail',
                'myemail.265@e.mail',
                'myemail.266@e.mail',
                'myemail.267@e.mail',
                'myemail.269@e.mail',
                'myemail.269@e.mail',
                'myemail.270@e.mail',
                'myemail.271@e.mail',
                'myemail.272@e.mail',
                'myemail.273@e.mail',
                'myemail.274@e.mail',
                'myemail.275@e.mail',
                'myemail.276@e.mail',
                'myemail.277@e.mail',
                'myemail.278@e.mail',
                'myemail.279@e.mail',
                'myemail.280@e.mail',
                'myemail.281@e.mail',
                'myemail.282@e.mail',
                'myemail.283@e.mail',
                'myemail.284@e.mail',
                'myemail.285@e.mail',
                'myemail.286@e.mail',
                'myemail.287@e.mail',
                'myemail.288@e.mail',
                'myemail.289@e.mail',
                'myemail.290@e.mail',
                'myemail.291@e.mail',
                'myemail.292@e.mail',
                'myemail.293@e.mail',
                'myemail.294@e.mail',
                'myemail.295@e.mail',
                'myemail.296@e.mail',
                'myemail.297@e.mail',
                'myemail.298@e.mail',
                'myemail.299@e.mail',
                'myemail.300@e.mail',
                'myemail.301@e.mail',
                'myemail.302@e.mail',
                'myemail.303@e.mail',
                'myemail.304@e.mail',
                'myemail.305@e.mail',
                'myemail.306@e.mail',
                'myemail.307@e.mail',
                'myemail.308@e.mail',
                'myemail.309@e.mail',
                'myemail.310@e.mail',
                'myemail.311@e.mail',
                'myemail.312@e.mail',
                'myemail.313@e.mail',
                'myemail.314@e.mail',
                'myemail.315@e.mail',
                'myemail.316@e.mail',
                'myemail.317@e.mail',
                'myemail.318@e.mail',
                'myemail.319@e.mail',
                'myemail.320@e.mail',
                'myemail.321@e.mail',
                'myemail.322@e.mail',
                'myemail.323@e.mail',
                'myemail.324@e.mail',
                'myemail.325@e.mail',
                'myemail.326@e.mail',
                'myemail.327@e.mail',
                'myemail.328@e.mail',
                'myemail.329@e.mail',
                'myemail.330@e.mail',
                'myemail.331@e.mail',
                'myemail.332@e.mail',
                'myemail.333@e.mail',
                'myemail.334@e.mail',
                'myemail.335@e.mail',
                'myemail.336@e.mail',
                'myemail.337@e.mail',
                'myemail.338@e.mail',
                'myemail.339@e.mail',
                'myemail.340@e.mail',
                'myemail.341@e.mail',
                'myemail.342@e.mail',
                'myemail.343@e.mail',
                'myemail.344@e.mail',
                'myemail.345@e.mail',
                'myemail.346@e.mail',
                'myemail.347@e.mail',
                'myemail.348@e.mail',
                'myemail.349@e.mail',
                'myemail.350@e.mail',
                'myemail.351@e.mail',
                'myemail.352@e.mail',
                'myemail.353@e.mail',
                'myemail.354@e.mail',
                'myemail.355@e.mail',
                'myemail.356@e.mail',
                'myemail.357@e.mail',
                'myemail.358@e.mail',
                'myemail.359@e.mail',
                'myemail.360@e.mail',
                'myemail.361@e.mail',
                'myemail.362@e.mail',
                'myemail.363@e.mail',
                'myemail.364@e.mail',
                'myemail.365@e.mail',
                'myemail.366@e.mail',
                'myemail.367@e.mail',
                'myemail.369@e.mail',
                'myemail.369@e.mail',
                'myemail.370@e.mail',
                'myemail.371@e.mail',
                'myemail.372@e.mail',
                'myemail.373@e.mail',
                'myemail.374@e.mail',
                'myemail.375@e.mail',
                'myemail.376@e.mail',
                'myemail.377@e.mail',
                'myemail.378@e.mail',
                'myemail.379@e.mail',
                'myemail.380@e.mail',
                'myemail.381@e.mail',
                'myemail.382@e.mail',
                'myemail.383@e.mail',
                'myemail.384@e.mail',
                'myemail.385@e.mail',
                'myemail.386@e.mail',
                'myemail.387@e.mail',
                'myemail.388@e.mail',
                'myemail.389@e.mail',
                'myemail.390@e.mail',
                'myemail.391@e.mail',
                'myemail.392@e.mail',
                'myemail.393@e.mail',
                'myemail.394@e.mail',
                'myemail.395@e.mail',
                'myemail.396@e.mail',
                'myemail.397@e.mail',
                'myemail.398@e.mail',
                'myemail.399@e.mail',
                'myemail.400@e.mail',
                'myemail.401@e.mail',
                'myemail.402@e.mail',
                'myemail.403@e.mail',
                'myemail.404@e.mail',
                'myemail.405@e.mail',
                'myemail.406@e.mail',
                'myemail.407@e.mail',
                'myemail.408@e.mail',
                'myemail.409@e.mail',
                'myemail.410@e.mail',
                'myemail.411@e.mail',
                'myemail.412@e.mail',
                'myemail.413@e.mail',
                'myemail.414@e.mail',
                'myemail.415@e.mail',
                'myemail.416@e.mail',
                'myemail.417@e.mail',
                'myemail.418@e.mail',
                'myemail.419@e.mail',
                'myemail.420@e.mail',
                'myemail.421@e.mail',
                'myemail.422@e.mail',
                'myemail.423@e.mail',
                'myemail.424@e.mail',
                'myemail.425@e.mail',
                'myemail.426@e.mail',
                'myemail.427@e.mail',
                'myemail.428@e.mail',
                'myemail.429@e.mail',
                'myemail.430@e.mail',
                'myemail.431@e.mail',
                'myemail.432@e.mail',
                'myemail.433@e.mail',
                'myemail.434@e.mail',
                'myemail.435@e.mail',
                'myemail.436@e.mail',
                'myemail.437@e.mail',
                'myemail.438@e.mail',
                'myemail.439@e.mail',
                'myemail.440@e.mail',
                'myemail.441@e.mail',
                'myemail.442@e.mail',
                'myemail.443@e.mail',
                'myemail.444@e.mail',
                'myemail.445@e.mail',
                'myemail.446@e.mail',
                'myemail.447@e.mail',
                'myemail.448@e.mail',
                'myemail.449@e.mail',
                'myemail.450@e.mail',
                'myemail.451@e.mail',
                'myemail.452@e.mail',
                'myemail.453@e.mail',
                'myemail.454@e.mail',
                'myemail.455@e.mail',
                'myemail.456@e.mail',
                'myemail.457@e.mail',
                'myemail.458@e.mail',
                'myemail.459@e.mail',
                'myemail.460@e.mail',
                'myemail.461@e.mail',
                'myemail.462@e.mail',
                'myemail.463@e.mail',
                'myemail.464@e.mail',
                'myemail.465@e.mail',
                'myemail.466@e.mail',
                'myemail.467@e.mail',
                'myemail.469@e.mail',
                'myemail.469@e.mail',
                'myemail.470@e.mail',
                'myemail.471@e.mail',
                'myemail.472@e.mail',
                'myemail.473@e.mail',
                'myemail.474@e.mail',
                'myemail.475@e.mail',
                'myemail.476@e.mail',
                'myemail.477@e.mail',
                'myemail.478@e.mail',
                'myemail.479@e.mail',
                'myemail.480@e.mail',
                'myemail.481@e.mail',
                'myemail.482@e.mail',
                'myemail.483@e.mail',
                'myemail.484@e.mail',
                'myemail.485@e.mail',
                'myemail.486@e.mail',
                'myemail.487@e.mail',
                'myemail.488@e.mail',
                'myemail.489@e.mail',
                'myemail.490@e.mail',
                'myemail.491@e.mail',
                'myemail.492@e.mail',
                'myemail.493@e.mail',
                'myemail.494@e.mail',
                'myemail.495@e.mail',
                'myemail.496@e.mail',
                'myemail.497@e.mail',
                'myemail.498@e.mail',
                'myemail.499@e.mail',
                'myemail.500@e.mail')
            );
            SET counter = counter + 1;
    end while;

end##
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

See the answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26578313/how-do-i-create-a-sequence-in-mysql) by @pupitetris to create a sequence table.  Replace your VALUES clause with a SELECT clause that selects FROM that sequence table, using the expressions that you already have to select random fname, lname, etc.