# Can Spring Batch use MySQL for its internal BATCH_ tables?

Tags: mysql, spring

I have been using Oracle for this without any trouble but I then had to switch it all over to use MySQL and am seeing this error during initialization:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Could not obtain sequence value; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown table 'BATCH_JOB_SEQ' in field list
```

The tables are present so its something else going wrong here. After debugging I captured the actual sql it was trying to perform to get the sequence:

```
select BATCH_JOB_SEQ.nextval from dual;
```

Which is obviously an Oracle statement!
My config states this to setup the connection:

```
     <bean id="springDataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://10.252.205.5:3306/MASKNG" />
      <property name="username" value="MASKNG" />
      <property name="password" value="maskng" />
  </bean>
```

Any help appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setDatabaseType（“mysql”）

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is no BATCH_JOB_SEQ created here in MySQL.
You need to create the sequence for that. Refer [How do I create a sequence in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26578313/how-do-i-create-a-sequence-in-mysql) for creating sequence.