# Hibernate select after insertion

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data

I'm having an issue with inserting new rows into my MySQL database.  I'm using Spring Boot with Spring Boot Data JPA.

Since MySQL doesn't support sequences, I decided to try and make my own sequence generator table.  This is basically what I've done.

1. I created a `sequences` table that uses an auto increment field (used as my id's for my tables).
2. Created a function, `sequences_nextvalue()` which inserts into the `sequences` table and returns the new auto incremented id.
3. I then created triggers on each table that get triggered before insertion and replaces the id field with the result of calling `sequences_nextvalue()`.

So this is working fine when inserting new rows.  I'm getting unique ids across all tables.  The issue I'm having is with my JPA entities.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class AbstractBaseClass {
  @Id
  private Integer id = -1;
  ...
}

@Entity
public class ConcreteClass1 extends AbstractBaseClass {
  ...
}


@Entity
public class ConcreteClass2 extends AbstractBaseClass {
  ...
}
```

I want to be able to query from the abstract base class so I've placed my `@Id` column in that class and used `@Entity` with `InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS`.  I've also initialized the id to -1 since an id is required to call `save()` from my spring crud repository.

After calling the `save()` function of my Spring data `CrudRepository`, the -1 for `id` properly gets replaced by the MySQL trigger but the resulting entity returned by `save()` doesn't return with the new id but instead retains the -1.  After looking at the SQL logs, a select statement is not being called after insertion to get the new id but instead the original entity is being returned.

Is it possible to force Hibnerate to re-select the entity after insertion to get the new id when you're not using `@GeneratedValue`?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: MySQL supports Sequence..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26578313/how-do-i-create-a-sequence-in-mysql

Comment: the problem with `AUTO_INCREMENT` is that is scoped so that each table has it's own `AUTO_INCREMENT` field which allows for overlapping id's.  I want to have unique id's across multiple tables meaning if I have id of 1 in `SOME_TABLE` there will not be an id of 1 in `ANOTHER_TABLE`.  So basically I want multiple tables to share and `AUTO_INCREMENT` field.

Comment: I already have this working but since I'm not using `@GeneratedValue`, Hibernate is not performing the `SELECT` it normally does after `INSERT` so I'm not getting the newly generated id in the returned entity on `save()`.  The id is stored properly in the database though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to provide an update on this question.  Here is my solution.

Instead of creating MySQL `TRIGGER`'s to replace the `id` on `INSERT`, I created a Hibernate `IdentifierGenerator` which executes a `CallableStatement` to get and return a new id.

My abstract base class now looks like this.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class AbstractBaseClass {

  @Id
  @GenericGenerator(name="MyIdGenerator", strategy="com.sample.model.CustomIdGenerator" )
    @GeneratedValue(generator="MyIdGenerator" )
  private Integer id;
  ...

}
```

and my generator looks like this.

```
public class CustomIdGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomIdGenerator.class);
    private static final String QUERY = "{? = call sequence_nextvalue()}";

    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object object) throws HibernateException {

        Integer id = null;
        try {
            Connection connection = session.connection();
            CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall(QUERY);
            statement.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
            statement.execute();
            id = statement.getInt(1);
        } catch(SQLException e) {
            log.error("Error getting id", e);
            throw new HibernateException(e);
        }
        return id;
    }

}
```

---

And just for reference

The `sequences` table.

```
CREATE TABLE sequences (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  thread_id INT NOT NULL,
  created DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ^;
```

The `sequence_nextvalue` function

```
CREATE FUNCTION sequence_nextvalue()
RETURNS INTEGER
NOT DETERMINISTIC
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
  DECLARE nextvalue INTEGER;
  INSERT INTO sequences (thread_id) VALUE (CONNECTION_ID());
  SELECT id FROM sequence_values ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1 INTO nextvalue;
  RETURN nextvalue;
END ^;
```