# Auto increment shared over multiple tables

Tags: mysql

For school, I am working on a project. In this project, I'm trying to create a sort of facebook like idea. You can write on your own profile, you can write on another one profile and you can share those with other people on their profile

I use PHP and Mysql for this.

This first step works perfectly. You can post a message on your own profile, it displays it nicely etc etc.
Now I am working on the writes, so I write something on another one's profile. I have a separate layout for them, just something that says
PERSONA wrote something on the profile of PERSONB
And then here the post

Layout importing isn't that big of a problem, the part where I struggle is how my database should look like.

Right now I have a separate table for the posts, writes, likes, comments, files(for images in the posts)

The problem I have with this setup is when I for example like a post with the id of 7, and also like a write with the id 7, it just won't work cus the likes table is just a table with 5 fields.
 1. id        Auto increment ID
 2. User_id    who has liked
 3. post_id --> if it is an post, insert the id here

The problem is, when a certain id is given, I don't know if it is meant for a post, a write or whatever.

The best way to solve this should be to have an Auto Increment ID across the

```
posts
writes
shares
```

So that an ID only exists in one of the 3, and I can check whatever it is meant to be.

If there are better ways of achieving this(and there probably are better ways) feel free to share it with me!

Comment: [Foreign key constraint](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) ?

Comment: How do other people handle this sort of thing?

Comment: Can you use a sequence? https://stackoverflow.com/a/26578578/3179169

Comment: posts and writes should probably be the same table unless they have some important structural differences.