# How to generate unique custom sequence id for employee code using java and mysql

Tags: java, mysql

Whenever i create new employee the employee code should be unique. For example,  employee code like E00001, E00002, E00003.

Comment: You can use AUTO_INCREMENT in mysql  for your id column, so they will allways be unique and after that, add an E at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

Create a sequence for generate employeeId  in MySQL : [how ? here the info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26578313/how-do-i-create-a-sequence-in-mysql)

```
//Get the sequence value and assign to local variable I am assuming value is 1 check below code

    String empIdNextSequence = String.valueOf(1);

            if (null != empIdNextSequence && empIdNextSequence.length() < 5)
            {
                int uuidNextSequenceLength = empIdNextSequence.length();
                for (int i = 0; i < 5 - uuidNextSequenceLength; i++)
                {
                    empIdNextSequence = "0".concat(empIdNextSequence);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("E"+empIdNextSequence);
```

Set empIdNextSequence value to your employeeCode