# i am creating sequence but i am getting error how to create sequence without existing table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sequence

1:create sequence on orders value 100 step 5;

2:create sequence CountBy1
start with 1
increment by 1;

Comment: mysql does not have sequence please publish the error message in full.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a sequence in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26578313/how-do-i-create-a-sequence-in-mysql)