# How can I add a number column that tracks deletions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

Is there a gem or some database logic which I can use to add a number column to my database that tracks adds and deletes?

For example, GitHub has issues. An issue has a database ID. But it also has a number which is like a human readable identifier. If an issue is deleted, the number continues to increase. And repo A can have an issue with a number, and that doesn’t conflict with repo B.

Comment: What you want sounds basically just like an ordinal column. On postgres you could do it with [a sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html) - on other DBs you have to create a separate table to accomplish the same thing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26578313/how-do-i-create-a-sequence-in-mysql

Comment: @max this is a great answer and I’d love to give you credit for it if you make it a reply.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new table add a column to the Table like  deleteCount. Everytime you call delete function or method. Just add a line that increments deleteCount like deleteCount++ to the success block. Same goes to the add method.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are overthinking it. The `id` column in rails (which all models possess by default) works the way you are thinking.

If you want a more human readable number as well, I would look at this gem (it has a ton of potential uses):
https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

Edit:

Looks like you might actually be looking for basically number of children of a parent. Logic looks like this:

1. When a parent is created a `child_count` column is set to 0
2. Whenever child is created for that parent, it increments the parent count, saves the result (this must be done atomically to avoid problems), which returns the current `child_count`
3. Set that `child_count` the childs `parent_child_id`.

The key trickly bit is that #2 has to be done atomically to avoid problems. So lock the row, update the column, then unlock the row.

Code roughly looks like:

```
# In Child model

after_commit :add_parent_child_id

def add_parent_child_id
  parent.with_lock do
    new_child_count = parent.child_count + 1
    parent.child_count = new_child_count
    parent.save!
    self.update!(parent_child_id: new_child_count)
  end
end
```

Comment: You're underthinking it. The id column is unique for the entire table. What the OP wants is an ordinal per parent record.

Comment: @max yes exactly! Do you know a solution?