# How to create custom sequence in mysql like in oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle

Hi I want to create custom sequence in mysql where in oracle I simply create the sequence by  :

```
CREATE SEQUENCE id_seq
    INCREMENT BY 10
    START WITH 10
    MINVALUE 10
    MAXVALUE 100
    CYCLE
    CACHE 2;
```

But how to do it in mysql;

Comment: What does `select version();` show?

Comment: It shows 8.0.28

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a sequence in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26578313/how-do-i-create-a-sequence-in-mysql)