# auto increment value in my column mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to make query that can auto increment in queue_number not just number 1 but every time i insert values into `queue_number` I want increment by + 1, and services column not change but just in `queue_number`

right down here just my basic code can you help me with this :)

```
INSERT INTO mytable (services, queue_number) values ('1', '1');
```

Comment: Can you add `AUTO_INCREMENT` to the  `services` column definition?

Comment: the value in servics just 1 but i want to increment just like serial number

Comment: in queue_number

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate a dynamic sequence table in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058816/how-to-generate-a-dynamic-sequence-table-in-mysql)

Comment: but my queue_number coloumn doesn't have AUTO_INCREMENT feature just INT type

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the field as AUTO_INCREMENT:

```
queue_number INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

On the insert, you don't need to specify it, it will auto-increment by 1 each time:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (services) values ('1');
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has the option 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE' that can do the trick.

First of all, make sure you have an unique index or primary key on the field "services":

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD UNIQUE INDEX 'services_key' ('services');
```

Then, when making the insert:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (services) values ('1') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE queue_number=queue_number+1;
```